# Access и символ новой строки

Tags: c#, access, ms-access, office

Делаю вставку из .NET в MS Access. Объединяю несколько строчек массива в единую строку через `\n` с помощью `string.join()`.

Так вот, почему-то после добавления данных в ячейку Access- эти данные визуально смотрятся как-будто идут единой строкой. Однако, если скопировать их в NotePad++, то на самом деле- это 2 разные строки и в конце стоит символ `CRLF`.

В тоже время в конце строки появляется какой-то пробельный символ, который удалить нельзя, а сам символ имеет код 10.

Почему-то при вставке отформатированного `XDocument` таких проблем не возникает и видно многострочное форматирования.

Access неправильно интерптирует `\n`?

Comment: *и в конце стоит символ `CRLF`* А ты проверь ДО копирования - там будет только LF. *символ имеет код 10* Угу, оно... *Объединяю несколько строчек массива в единую строку через `\n`* А если через `\r\n`? *Access неправильно интерптирует `\n`* Будь он юниксовый - интерпретировал бы правильно...

Comment: @Akina, да. СейчасEnvironment.NewLine все прокатило.

Answer (score 0):

Хм... оказывается NotePad++ слишком умный и сам ставит недостающий символ.

Проблема решилась путем добавления `Environment.NewLine`, что эквивалентно `\r\n`